# How make a equation in OpenOffice

Tags: openoffice.org, equations

How to make a system of equation in OpenOffice?

```
f(%ksi) = left lbrace stack #(2 (x-a)) over ((b-a)(c-a))# #(2(b-x)) over
((b-a)(b-c)# right none
```

It doesn't not work.

Comment: your question is unclear, but i suggest you simplify whatever you are doing, until "it works" and the last step you removed/simplified away, is what is your problem, and then you can ask a more specific question.

Comment: If you can't find any relevant answer you can also try asking in [openoffice's forum](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/index.php). That being said I think you need to put curly braces for the stack : `f(%ksi) = left lbrace stack { (2 (x-a)) over ((b-a)(c-a))# #(2(b-x)) over ((b-a)(b-c) } right none`. Can't try it myself though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
f(%ksi) = left lbrace stack {
    { (2 (x-a)) over ((b-a)(c-a)) } #
    { (2 (b-x)) over ((b-a)(b-c)) }
} right none
```

resulting in

[image]

<sub>*(tested with LibreOffice Math 5.0.1.2)*</sub>